# Pandas add time (dd-mm-yyyy XX:XX AM/PM) and integer (represent in minutes)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset in which Column A represents staring time of webinar e.g. Apr 16, 2020 9:13 AM
In second column, i have webinar duration in minutes e.g. 70

I want to create third column where webinar end time will come e.g.  Apr 16, 2020 10:23 AM

I tried converting both columns into pd_datetime() format, but it is showing error.

data['Actual Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Actual Duration'])
data['Webinar start time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Webinar start time'])
data['Webinar end time'] = data['Webinar start time'].dt.time + data['Actual Duration'].dt.time

Comment: Share a sample of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for timedeltas and then add to datetimes, converting to time is not necessary:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Webinar start time':['Apr 16, 2020 9:13 AM'], 'Actual Duration':[70]})

data['Webinar start time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Webinar start time'])
data['Actual Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Actual Duration'], unit='Min') 
data['Webinar end time'] = data['Webinar start time'] + data['Actual Duration']
print (data)
   Webinar start time Actual Duration    Webinar end time
0 2020-04-16 09:13:00        01:10:00 2020-04-16 10:23:00
```

Comment: invalid unit abbreviation: Apr
--- This error is coming.

Comment: @user11259102 - Sorry, I swap column names, need `data['Actual Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Actual Duration'], unit='Min') ` and `data['Webinar start time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Webinar start time'])`

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. However i am still getting error ----> dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

Comment: @user11259102 - column `Actual Duration` is filled by `numbers`, like `70` ?

Comment: from datetime import timedelta  ---> I added this at start and your code worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.timedelta` to calculate the end with a Lambda function:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': 'Apr 16, 2020 9:13 AM', 'duration': 70}])

def add_time(row):
    return row['date'] + timedelta(minutes=row['duration'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['end'] = df.apply(add_time, axis=1)
print(df.head())
#                  date  duration                 end
# 0 2020-04-16 09:13:00        70 2020-04-16 10:23:00
```

Comment: from datetime import timedelta   ---> i added this in earlier code and its worked. Thanks!!